# Import youtube-dl directly from git repository into ipython

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I have forked and checked out the youtube-dl repository from github. I would like to import youtube-dl directly from my git directory without having to install it, to test my changes in the code. Is this possible? How do I do this?

Comment: For me, `import youtube_dl` in the root of the Git repo works

Comment: Thank you, it works for me too! How can I be sure that this is the version from the git directory and not the one installed by my package manager on my system?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply `cd` into the project root and then `import youtube_dl`.

To clarify that this is the version you want instead of `pip`'s version, look at the value of `youtube_dl.__file__` to see where the module is located:

```
In [1]: import youtube_dl

In [2]: youtube_dl.__file__
Out[2]: 'C:\\Users\\Me\\Documents\\youtube-dl\\youtube_dl\\__init__.py'
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the project readme, the [developer instruction](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl#developer-instructions) section is what you are searching for.

If you want to separate your work in the directory from the system version of the module you could look at [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), a tool to isolate your projects dependencies.